# For in loop is showing the img tag instead of the actualy Giphy gif

Tags: javascript, api, giphy-api

I'm trying to make a giphy clone and I want to display six of the trending gifs at the moment. However, when I run the code it seems to work fine in the sense of being able to grab the image source from the response data but the actual gif is not being displayed.

I tried using some of the different url and mp4 links provided in the response data but it always ends up displaying just the image tag.

```
function getTrending() {

  // Create AJAX request to get the trending gifs

  // Create the new XHR object

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Call the open function with a GET-type request, url, and set async to true

  xhr.open('GET', 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?&api_key=<MyApiKey>&limit=6', true);

  // Call the onload function

  xhr.onload = function() {
    // Check if the server status is 200
    if(this.status === 200) {
      // Return server response as an object using JSON.parse
      let trendingResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      // Create for in loop to insert the trending gifs into the gif container div

      for (i in trendingResponse.data) {
        gifsContainer.append("<img src='"+ trendingResponse.data[i].images.original.url+"' />")
      }

      console.log(trendingResponse.data[1]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because when you use [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append), you are actually appending actual text instead of an element/node to your `gifsContainer`:

> The `ParentNode.append()` method inserts a set of `Node` objects or `DOMString` objects after the last child of the `ParentNode`. `DOMString` objects are inserted as equivalent `Text` nodes.

You should construct the image element by using [`new Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) and then append it instead:

```
for (i in trendingResponse.data) {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = trendingResponse.data[i].images.original.url;

    gifsContainer.append(image);
}
```

If you're more comfortable using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), that's also possible:

```
for (i in trendingResponse.data) {
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = trendingResponse.data[i].images.original.url;

    gifsContainer.append(image);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That resolved the issue.